# HEVC file decoding using HEVC HM decoder refrence

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hevc, h.265

I'm trying to use HEVC HM reference code to decode a scalable HEVC file with losses. But it seems like the decoder works well when there is no losses, but when I try to decode a corrupted file (experiencing some losses, in base and/or enhancement packets), it seems like the decoder skip all the following frames when it failed to decode a frame.

I am using the following command line to decode the file.

/bin/TAppDecoderStatic -b input-file.265 -o output-file.yuv

Is there any particular option to overcome this limitation or maybe a patch available for HM. I'm open to use any other decoder too. I've tried ffmpeg, but it seems encountering the same issue.
Thanks.

Comment: You need certain previous frames to decode following frames. If none are uncorrupted then those following frames may not decode properly or at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the problem even if it doesn't succeed to decode a picture (like with ffmpeg, I got a missing picture error) , I think it has to try to decode the following ones.  is it correct? Or to show missing slices in the video (black pixels). But, for now, It just decodes the "correct " frames. For example it decodes only the 3 first pictures, and then skip all the others. I was using the same pattern losses for H264, and the decoder was able to decode till the end. And when it encounters losses, I can see black pixels and missing slices in the video.

Answer (score 0):

Decoder fails to decode frames after getting an erroneous frame or slice until the next key frame due to high temporal dependencies. Try to use an input which has periodic key frames or use a decoder which support robust error concealment techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have please any recommendations for robust decoders?